# override method not called from pointer to base class

Tags: c++

```
class Shape {
public:
    virtual Shape* create() { return new Shape(); }
    virtual ~Shape() {}
};

class Circle : public Shape {
public:
    virtual Circle* create() override { return new Circle(); }
};

int main() {
    Shape *sp = new Circle();
    Circle *cr = sp->create(); // invalid conversion from ‘Shape*’ to ‘Circle*’
    delete sp;
}
```

Why is that, shouldn't `Circle::create()` get called?

- the call is not inside a constructor.
- `Circle::create()` does override - no compiler error.

Comment: `Circle::create()` is getting called, but the *return type* of `sp->create()` is still `Shape*`.

Comment: @BoPersson But then, why does the return type is `Shape*`?

Comment: Because `sp` is declared as `Shape *` and that's what `Shape::create`'s return type is.

Comment: @melpomene but `Shape::create` is not getting called, `Circle::create` does.

Comment: Type checking happens at compile time (according to the declared types of your variables). Calls are a runtime issue.

Comment: @melpomene think I got it, thanks.

Comment: @melpomene: Please make your answers answers rather than comments...

Comment: @einpoklum I'll start doing that when OP makes their questions questions rather than comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `create()` is defined in base class. The method signatures must be the same in order to override a method in derived class. But the thing here is that **return type is not included to method signatures**. This is why you are seeing the return type of call `sp->create()` is still in type `Shape *`.